# How can I set foldlevelstart in vim to just fold nothing initially, still allowing zr to work immediately?

Tags: vim, vimrc, code-folding

In vim, I typically set `foldmethod` to `indent` for most file types. In general, I like files to open with all folds open. However, it is useful to start immediately using <kbd>zm</kbd> to start closing folds globally across the file, one level at a time, allowing me to see the overall structure of the file without details getting in the way.

The only general solution I have found is to set `foldlevelstart` to a very high number, e.g. 99, to make sure that all files (bearing in mind different files will have different levels of maximum indent) start completely unfolded. However, I'd then have to use <kbd>zm</kbd> repeatedly to reduce `foldlevel` down to the maximum fold level of the file, normally much less than 99, which is cumbersome and impractical. I could set `foldlevel` manually using the vim command line, but I'd still need to know the maximum indent in the file.

Is there a practical way to open a file with `foldlevel` set to exactly one more than the maximum current indent/fold level in the file itself?

For example, given the following file:

```
a
  b
    c
      d1
      d2
    e
      f1
      f2
```

The first keypress of <kbd>zm</kbd> would show this:

```
a
  b
    c
+--  2 lines: d1------
    e
+--  2 lines: f1------
```

(Note, however, that it should work for the general case where the initial maximum indent of the file could be any value).

Comment: You're confusing `zr` with `zm`; the latter _reduces_ the foldlevel.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, you're right, I am. Sorry for the confusion - I always find those key combos counter-intuitive. I've fixed my question.

Comment: _"I always find those key combos counter-intuitive."_ It's supposed to mean `zm` = fold more (subtract foldlevel) and `zr` = fold less (add foldlevel)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This finds the highest foldlevel in the current file:

```
:let &foldlevel = max(map(range(1, line('$')), 'foldlevel(v:val)'))
```

To set this automatically, you can use an `:autocmd`:

```
:autocmd BufWinEnter * let &foldlevel = max(map(range(1, line('$')), 'foldlevel(v:val)'))
```

Comment: Ingo, perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Shame `foldlevelstart` doesn't have a option like this.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Cygwin Vim. My `foldlevel`is 0  and `foldlevelstart` is -1 when I launch a file with those settings.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `zr`, use `zR`, which will open all folds. Similarly, `zM` will close all folds.

Comment: Gary, thanks. That's close, but doesn't do what I describe. I'd like a command that reduces the folding level just by one, but from the maximum fold level relevant to the file in question. To do that, I'd need to use zM to reduce the foldlevel to 0, then zr repeatedly to open up more of the detail. I'm looking for one command/key combination.

Comment: You can do `zR` (set foldlevel to highest level) then `zm` will work. It's just one extra step.

Answer (score -1):

The option `set nofoldenable` lets you start off the file with all folds open

Comment: That's not the question I asked. I want folding enabled.